# Turning off IE 8 compatiblity mode

Tags: java, javascript, css, jsp, internet-explorer

My company uses IE8 as the default browser and by default compatibility mode is set for all intranet sites.

I have checked my application on IE8 and look and feel is totally hap hazard. But on chrome and Mozilla look and feel is fine.

Some one suggested me to turn off compatible mode.

there are two ways : 
1) IE>tools>Compatible view settings > ( unchecked ) Display intranet sites...

2) Put `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />` on jsp pages.

I checked and my application looks fine when I turn off compatibility mode.

My Questions :

1) What is the use of compatibility  mode.

2) If I turn it off through JSP page, what are the other impact. ( does it like on IE11 , if I change compatible it to IE9 then my application will not work as expected.)

3) Turning off compatible mode is only solution or is there anything else I can do

4) Is there any other impact.

Comment: welcome to the wonderful world of coding for IE

Comment: turning off compatibility mode won't have much impact other than the way the browser renders the page.

Comment: At least IE 10+ actually makes a valid attempt to support standards. IE 9 doesn't support strict mode, and IE 8 hardly supports ES5. IE8+ do largely support HTML 4.01 and CSS 2.1 but that was only when things started getting consistent cross-browser.

Answer (score 1):

From the linked MSDN page:

> Internet Explorer 8 supports many compatibility modes that enable
>   different supported features and affect the manner in which content is
>   rendered. For example,
>
> IE5 mode renders content as if it were displayed by the Windows
>   Internet Explorer 7 Quirks mode, which is very similar to how
>   Microsoft Internet Explorer 5 displayed content.
>
> IE7 mode renders content as if it were displayed by the Internet
>   Explorer 7 Standards mode, whether or not the page contains a
>    directive.
>
> EmulateIE7 mode tells Windows Internet Explorer to use the 
>   directive to determine how to render content. Standards mode
>   directives are displayed in Internet Explorer 7 Standards mode, and
>   Quirks mode directives are displayed in IE5 mode. Unlike IE7 mode,
>   EmulateIE7 mode respects the  directive. For many Web sites,
>   this is the preferred compatibility mode.
>
> EmulateIE8 mode is similar to EmulateIE7 mode; Internet Explorer uses
>   the  directive to determine how to render content; however,
>   standards mode directives are displayed in Internet Explorer 8
>   Standards mode. Quirks mode directives are displayed in IE5 mode.
>
> IE8 mode provides the highest support available for industry
>   standards, including the W3C Cascading Style Sheets Level 2.1
>   Specification and the W3C Selectors API, as well as limited support
>   for the W3C Cascading Style Sheets Level 3 Specification (Working
>   Draft).
>
> Edge mode tells Windows Internet Explorer to display content in the
>   highest mode available, which actually breaks the “lock-in” paradigm.
>   With Internet Explorer 8, this is equivalent to IE8 mode. If a
>   (hypothetical) future release of Internet Explorer supported a higher
>   compatibility mode, pages set to Edge mode would appear in the highest
>   mode supported by that version; however, those same pages would still
>   appear in IE8 mode when viewed with Internet Explorer 8. It is
>   recommended that Web developers restrict their use of Edge mode to
>   test pages and other non-production uses because of the possible
>   unexpected results of rendering page content in future versions of
>   Windows Internet Explorer.
>
> By default, Internet Explorer 8 uses EmulateIE8 mode to display pages
>   loaded from the Internet Zone. Web pages loaded from the Intranet Zone
>   or with the Web Browser control are displayed in EmulateIE7 mode.

[Source : msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/cc817574.aspx)

Comment: Who actually tries to support IE5 anymore? The earliest one I've heard of supported this year was IE6, and it's primarily of banks and other places that tend to keep internal tech change to a bare minimum (many others in this group are also still using DOS).

Comment: Yeah.. I second you on that. Infact after the departure of XP even IE7 support is not required.